# Why is Momoshiki Ōtsutsuki's Rinnegan of a different color?

Tags: boruto

In episodes 63-65 of the Boruto anime, Momoshiki Ōtsutsuki's Rinnegan has changed its color, compared with the color of the usual Rinnegans or from the movie *Boruto: Naruto Next Generations*? Could this mean Rinnegan also has variations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Rinnegan has variations especially that of Momoshiki's where it is depicted in different colors:

> Momoshiki Ōtsutsuki has a pair of Rinnegan embedded in the palms of his hands. They are initially red, but after he consumes his guardian, Kinshiki, they become **purple** (in Boruto: Naruto the Movie) or **yellow** (in Boruto: Naruto Next Generations). This also grants him a third Rinnegan on his forehead, which matches the other two in colour. In the anime, Momoshiki's **yellow** Rinnegan temporarily turn **red** when he uses their power.

Source: https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Rinnegan